# How to import MySQL data using Sqoop in Python?

Tags: python, sqoop

This is the code I wrote in terminal and works perfectly fine.

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDb --username Amel -password Amel@-1998 --table mock3`

I want to do the same thing but on PyCharm. What setting or lines of code should I use?

I'm quite new and I've been doing plenty of research but I can't find a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your commands by calling `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["echo", "Hello", "World"])  # substitute your command as an array of strings
```

```
import os
os.system("echo Hello World")  #  substitute your command
```

There is also a library called `pysqoop` to use sqoop, check details from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pysqoop/). Your IDE (Pycharm) does not affect the solution.

Comment: Seems `pysqoop` import method is broken with a missing import